# How to add a context menu to a button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm completely new to WPF and I'm trying to get an existing button to display a dropdown with menu items.

What's the best approach to this?

```
<Button Name="ModelReport" Template="{StaticResource GlassButton}"
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MouseEnter="ModelReport_MouseEnter" Click="CommandButton_Click">

  <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,4,5,4">
    <Image Width="16" Height="16" x:Name="ModelReportImage" Source="{StaticResource MyImgScrollInformation}" />
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0">Model Report</TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>

</Button>
```

Comment: What approaches have you tried and what do you think about those. Please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to add a context menu to a button in WPF:

```
<Button Content="1234">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="abcd" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

**However it's confusing and bad UX !**

Unless the user precisely knows there is a context menu at this specific button, it's simply not visible in the user interface.

**Better approach:**

A split button.

[image]

There is one in the free version or [Extended WPF Toolkit Community Edition](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SplitButton&referringTitle=Home).